# SQL query, choosing the nearest DateTime data from two column in different tables

Tags: php, android, mysql, sql

I would like to only show the nearest DateTime data from an SQL query but the data is across two table. I have the code `SocialDatabase.SocialStart > NOW() LIMIT 1` to pick the most recent data from one table and I know `TrainingDatabase.SocialStart > NOW() LIMIT 1` would do the same thing for the other table.

So how would I go about merging these together to only get the nearest data from the combined list of the SocialDatabase and TrainingDatabase tables

Thanks

Comment: Please provide your database schema.

Comment: In addition to your schema, sample data and desired results would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**UNION**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/union.html) syntax:

```
(select SocialStart, Data from SocialDatabase where SocialDatabase.SocialStart > now() limit 1)
union
(select SocialStart, Data from TrainingDatabase where TrainingDatabase.SocialStart > now() limit 1)
order by 1 desc limit 1
```

Comment: I just worked this out and I was about to post my own answer. But I'll let you have it, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `view` - it's a virtual table in memory, and run a select on it.

example:

```
create view tmp as select id, timestamp from SocialDatabase.SocialStart order by timestamp asc limit 1;
insert into tmp select id, timestamp from TrainingDatabase.SocialStart order by timestamp asc limit 1;
select id,timestamp from tmp where timestamp>now() order by timestamp asc limit 1;
```

..or you can do it more simple - two selects and one compare in java code.